# Finding jacobian pattern to specify `jpattern` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to understand how to specify the jacobian pattern in ode settings of MATLAB's ode solver.

I've started with a simple example,

```
syms x y z;
F = [x*y, cos(x*z), log(3*x*z*y)]
v = [x y z]
J = jacobian(F,v)
```

gives,

```
J =
 
[           y,   x,           0]
[ -z*sin(x*z),   0, -x*sin(x*z)]
[         1/x, 1/y,         1/z]
```

I would like to generate the jacobian pattern
[Jacobian sparsity pattern, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'JPattern' and a sparse matrix. The sparse matrix contains 1s where there might be nonzero entries in the Jacobian](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) to speed up the computation.

Therefore, from J I'd like to generate the `jpattern` matrix,

```
jpattern = 
[ 1,   1,  0]
[ 1,   0,  1]
[ 1,   1,  1]
```

Suggestions on how to generate the `jpattern` from `Jacobian` will be really helpful.

Comment: btw a sparse matrix is useful only if it contains many many zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the desired [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) `jpattern` matrix, initialize it by the [size](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) of `J` and then [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) indices of possible non-zero entries of `J` and update the corresponding entries in `jpattern` to `1`.

```
[jr, jc] = size(J);
jpattern = sparse(jr, jc);
jpattern(find(J~=0)) = 1;
```

```
>> full(jpattern)
ans =
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     1     1     1
```